# PHP- Failed to save Base64 string to an image file

Tags: php, image, file-io, base64

I have to save base64 file on my local drive, but image corrupted when I have use file_put_contents.

I am able to see the image in my browser using following tag, but when I am using file_put_contents so it's not working.

```
$data = '<img src="data:image/png;base64,'.$image.'"/>';
```

code:

```
$data = '<img src="data:image/png;base64,'.$image.'"/>';
 //$data = str_replace(' ','+',$data);
  $decoded=base64_decode($image);

file_put_contents('/opt/lampp/htdocs/image.png',$decoded);
```

here is my encoded image content:
http://pastebin.com/PtzmceJe

Comment: When you are writing to file seems like you are also writing the img tag, can you try

$decoded=base64_decode($image);

Comment: i have also tried $decoded=base64_decode($image);

Comment: I am able to save image, but the image got corrupted.

Comment: Can you show your encoded data? means `$image` content.

Comment: Open the saved image in notepad.. does it start with `%PNG`? If not then the data in the base64 string is either not a PNG, or is already corrupted.

Comment: encoded image content: http://pastebin.com/PtzmceJe

Comment: That is a GIF mate. Converting that pastebin reveals the header `GIF87ax`, so you need to save it as `image.gif`

Comment: Here it is as a gif ... http://imgur.com/sWiwYaX

Comment: i have tried with $decoded = base64_decode($image);
    $file = 'data.gif';
   file_put_contents($file, $decoded);

Comment: Also if the pastebin you provided is from `var_dump($image)`, then it is not a string, it is actually a `SimpleXMLElement`, and `base64_decode` needs a string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Going on the base64 string you have pasted here: http://pastebin.com/PtzmceJe the image is a GIF. The filename is sometimes important depending on the image viewer or OS..

Change your code to this...

```
$decoded = base64_decode($image);
file_put_contents('/opt/lampp/htdocs/image.gif',$decoded);
```

.. and it should work for you.

You can see the converted output here https://i.stack.imgur.com/T43VU.jpg as a GIF.

Answer (score 1):

You have to remove the image tag and only use the `src` of the tag. String should look like:

> data:image/gif;base64,2CiVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhE

**Saving the base64 encoded image**

```
    <?php
    //explode at ',' - the last part should be the encoded image now
    $exp = explode(',', $data);
    //we just get the last element with array_pop
    $base64 = array_pop($exp);
    //decode the image and finally save it
    $data = base64_decode($base64);
    //take care of your file extension
    $file = 'image.gif';
    //make sure you are the owner and have the rights to write content
    file_put_contents($file, $data);
```

Or directly use the `$image` variable you have.

```
    <?php
    //decode the image and finally save it
    $data = base64_decode($image);
    $file = 'data.png';
    //make sure you are the owner and have the rights to write content
    file_put_contents($file, $data);
```

Comment: The explode is not need as OP already has the base64 string in the `$image` variable.

Comment: yeah I wanted to give an more general answer, since people normally have to extract it first. I edited it for his needs tho.

Comment: In that case you might want to explode the `$base64` one again to take off the `" />` that will be on the end of it. or just use regex :P

Comment: I told him just to take the src attrivute, so expected no "/>" in the end.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you are wiring wrong content:

```
$data = '<img src="data:image/png;base64,'.$image.'"/>';
//$decoded=base64_decode($data); wrong $data
$decoded=base64_decode($image); //corrent


file_put_contents('/opt/lampp/htdocs/image.png',$decoded);
```

Or it may be write permission issue or path issue, try:

```
file_put_contents('image.png',$decoded);// if dir having write permission it should work then try with complete path
```